# POST request to score using Cloud Model

Tags: r, post, spss, httr, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix and the new SPSS Predictive Modelling service. I want to score some data using a model that I deployed in the cloud. In the documentation I have the following Request example:

```
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Parameters:
        Path parameters:
            contextId: the identifier of the deployed model to be used to process this score request
        Query Parameters:
            accesskey: access_key from env.VCAP_SERVICES
        Body: the input data, json string, eg.
            {
                "tablename":"DRUG1n.sav", 
                "header":["Age", "Sex", "BP", "Cholesterol", "Na", "K", "Drug"], 
                "data":[[43.0, "M", "LOW", "NORMAL", 0.526102, 0.027164, "drugY"]]
            }
```

I want to do the request using R and the httr package. I wrote the following code:

```
library(httr)
#Score using a deployed predictive model
host = "https://ibmpmsrvus1.pmservice.ibmcloud.com:8443/pm/v1/score/"
access_key = "vvZ0DIc1d/oAzguseZS/cDf98us5bgi41pau9YEOtu81pRuVE1E2ND6v469pmmerEC2a6an71wxIdhb3gIZ5P7jnBaXJcLpJ+Ta+djR1Uu20nSZ+Rw9rXoOuXOuFsYgUnnipl9lQKr1S2ukXJrA2wA=="
contextId="drug"
url <- paste(host,contextId,"?accesskey=",access_key, sep = "")
data<-toJSON(list("tablename"= unbox("scoreInput"),
              "header" = c("Age", "Sex", "BP", "Cholesterol", "Na", "K","Drug"),
              "data" = c(unbox(43.0),"M","LOW","NORMAL",0.526102,0.027164,"drugY")
```

))
    r<-POST(url,body = data, encode = 'json')
    r

The json generated using the `toJSON` is a bit different:

```
{"tablename":"scoreInput","header":["Age","Sex","BP","Cholesterol","Na","K","Drug"],
"data":["43","M","LOW","NORMAL","0.526102","0.027164","drugY"]}
```

without the `[[` at the beginning of data, and that is why it is not working. How can I add this double [?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a content type like this:

```
r<-POST(url,body = data, content_type_json())
```

Comment: Reinstall httr package. Maybe you have an older one?

Comment: You are right, i have multiple versions of R installed in my machine and I had RStudio working with R2.15.1.... now it is accepting the request but still something is wrong, i get `status 500` which means The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Comment: Maybe also look at switching all of your double quotes for single word and vice versa in data. Does tablename need a file extension?

Comment: I solved, the JSON that I was sending in the body was wrong, I was to put double `[`
Using Matrix was solved: 

 `data<-toJSON(list("tablename"= unbox("scoreInput"),
                  "header" = c("Age", "Sex", "BP", "Cholesterol", "Na", "K","Drug"),
                  "data" = matrix(c(unbox(43.0),"M","LOW","NORMAL",0.526102,0.027164,"drugY"), nrow = 1, ncol = 7)
  )) `